# Are JSON transfers automatically encrypted when the server is on Heroku?

Tags: json, web-services, security, ssl, heroku

I was thinking that I needed more secure ways to transfer data between my app and my server on Heroku. I'm worried about MITM attacks. Then I noticed that the web server uses an https address. Does this mean that the JSON I'm sending to the server is automatically encrypted? What about when the server sends JSON back to the client?

Answer (score 0):

If the link the JSON request goes to starts with https then yes. JSON is just content sent over http/https and responses are sent over the same method as the query.

However, if you are on a webpage and there is an ajax call made in the background, then maybe not.

In all cases, it depends on where the http get request goes to: if it starts with https then  you are fine.

It sounds like your saying the request for json data is made over https, in wich case you are fine.